# Counter for entries to show most read Articles

Tags: entries, entry

How can I add a counter or something similar to my entries, so that I could loop through the most read articles?

Comment: There is a [counter plugin](http://straightupcraft.com/craft-plugins/counter) that is designed to do exactly this, which is currently in private beta written by Ben Croker. Perhaps if you contact the developer, he might let you participate in the beta.

Comment: @DouglasMcDonald Might want to post that as an actual answer ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Updated: There is an [Entry Count](https://www.putyourlightson.net/craft-entry-count) plugin that is designed to do exactly this, written by Ben Croker. Thanks Ben!

Comment: Note that this has been replaced by [Entry Count](https://github.com/putyourlightson/craft-entry-count).

Comment: The Entry Count plugin is available at https://www.putyourlightson.net/craft-entry-count

Answer (score 1):

The [Entry Count](https://www.putyourlightson.net/craft-entry-count) plugin will do this for you (previously the Counter plugin).

You can loop through the most read articles as follows:

```
{% set countedEntries = craft.entryCount.entries %}

{% for entry in countedEntries %}
    {% set count = craft.entryCount.count(entry.id) %}
    {{ entry.title }} ({{ count }} views)
{% endfor %}
```